# How to create cronjob in windows 7?

Tags: javascript, php, cron, phpmyadmin, dom-events

I want to create a counter for my website. It must be able to connect with my database every 24 hours, and show me the sum of Column "eure". This is my code but it doesn't work very well.

In my code I don't have any error, the problem is I don't know how I can automatically run my code every 24 hours.

Right now in order to see the sum of the column "eure" I must refresh the page ...
Could you explain me in details, please?

I know that I can use the cronjob, but I don't know how, and I don't know how I can install it for my program.

Please give tell me in details to make it easy.

I don't understand how I can use cronjob!

```
<?php
pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=base_test user=postgres password=123456") or die('could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var interv;
var encours;

function incrementer()
{
<?php
$q='select SUM("eure")from "compteur"'; 
$query=pg_query($q);
$n=pg_num_rows($query);
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
                {
                $f=pg_fetch_row($query);
                }
?>
document.formulaire.heure.value="<?php echo("$f[0]") ?>";
}

function appui()
{
    if(encours == 1)
    {
        clearInterval(interv);
        document.formulaire.bouton.value = "Reprendre";
        encours = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        interv = setInterval("incrementer()",100);
        document.formulaire.bouton.value = "Arrêter";
        encours = 1;
    }
}

function init()
{
    document.formulaire.bouton.value = "Commencer";
}

</script>

<body onload="init();">
<h2>Un compteur en JS</h2>
<form name="formulaire">
<input type="text" value="" name="heure" onclick="incrementer();"/> 
<input type="button" value="Arreter" onclick="appui();" name="bouton" />
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Is the server running Windows 7 or Linux? Cron is not available on Windows, you need to use the task scheduler there. Apart from that this is not a script you can run on a server via cron only; you would need just a php script that for example mails you the results. Your html and javascript will not work server-side.

Answer (score 0):

did you search for schedule task in windows

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task

Comment: i have 2 question! first, is the Task Scheduler is good for my project ? because in i went that my counter show the final (eure) in my site and evry 24h00 it connect with my data base and show the final (eure) because my data base do updated evry 24h00...

Answer (score 0):

Create PHP script and refer below link:

http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00487/0/Setup-Cron-job-on-Windows-7-Vista-2008.html